# Why Lord Shiva called as Samvatsarakara?

Tags: shiva, name

In Shiva Sahasranāmstrotram, one of names of Shiva is Samvatsarakara.

Why is he called so? Is/Was there a calendar associated with Lord Shiva?

Comment: Calender? Why do you think a calendar could be associated with shiva? I mean you read it anywhere?

Comment: No i have not read about this anywhere. But since one of His names is "Samvatsarakara" which means because of whom the year is, i thought maybe there could be a calendar assoiciated with Him, about which i am not aware of. Hence i asked here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sloka 57 of the Shiva-Sahasra-nAma reads

> **samvatasaras** tvam ritabo maso mAsardham eva cha--meaning [Lord Shiva!You are] the year, the seasons, the month, and the halves of the months .

The sloka 81 reads

> chandrAvarto yugAvartah samvartah **sampravartakah**---meaning [You are] the Mover of the Moon along its orbit, the month and the initiator and changer of the yugas.

'Samvatsarakara' is NOT there according to the text available to me.However, they connote the same meaning.

The Lord is everything and He is the Doer of everything. He is KAla (the Time) Himself and naturally He is the maker of the year, the year and all parts of the year Himself. So ALL calenders are associated with Lord Shiva.

In Vishu-SahasranAma also we get

> 'ahah samvatsaro varshah' etc as the names of Lord Vishnu. So the basic connotation is the same and both are parts of the Mahabharata.